# Unable establish secure connection with IBM MQ from MQI client

Tags: ibm-mq

I am trying to make a secure connection with MQ with the below command:

```
./amqssslc -c CLI.QM1.T -x <remote_server> -k clientkey -s <SOME CIPHE NAME>
```

I have created the clientkey.kdb using below commands:

```
runmqakm -keydb -create -db clientkey.kdb -pw passw0rd -type pkcs12 -expire 1000 -stash
runmqakm -cert -add -label QM1.cert -db clientkey.kdb -stashed -trust enable -file /root.cer
```

I got the below error:

```
No OCSP configuration specified.
MQCONNX ended with reason code 2393

Error in the log file :

AMQ9620E: Internal error on call to SSL function on channel 'CLI.QM1.T' to
host 'host-name'.

EXPLANATION:
An error indicating a software problem was returned from a function which is
used to provide SSL or TLS support. The error code returned was '9'. The
function call was 'gsk_environment_init'. 

The channel is 'CLI.QM1.T'; in some cases its name cannot be determined and
so is shown as '????'. The channel did not start. 

The remote host name is 'host-name'.
ACTION:
Collect the items listed in the 'Problem determination' section of the System
Administration manual and use either the MQ Support site:
http://www.ibm.com/software/integration/wmq/support/, or IBM Support Assistant
(ISA): http://www.ibm.com/software/support/isa/, to see whether a solution is
already available.  If you are unable to find a match, contact your IBM support
center.
```

can you please help me to solve this? I am using IBM MQ 9.1.0.11 version.

Besides, I got the private key name.p12 should I use this somewhere to establish the connection from MQ Client

Comment: 9.1 requires a CMS keystore, pkcs12 keystores will not work.  (Note that in 9.3 support pkcs12 keystores was added).  If the QMgr is expecting you to present a private key then you would also need to load that in the CMS keystore.

Comment: I have just created the keystores with CMS still the same error for me anything that I am missing?

Comment: What error shows up in the AMQERR01.LOG? Is it the same error? Is it from the queue manager or client logs? Can you provide any error from the log you have not provided, either queue manager or client.